# Javascript function to save new fields from existing fields (migration) in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

We have a design change in application to accommodate few new requirements. Design change forced us to migrate one of mongodb collection, instead of having individual fields, have to create a derived JSON string as a field from existing fields.

The migration process will be invoked by end-user doing a action in UI (like saving a change).  But that one action might update few thousands of documents.  So we would like to write Javascript code to be executed on server side, so that we can avoid loading many records to application.

But the issue we running into is, cannot call the java script function using eval as the collection is sharded. And other option we cannot consider is to make the collection un-sharded as the migration has to happen on live system.

Please help us if you know of any alternate approach.

Example migration : ExampleDoc (collection) has fields a1, a2, b1 and b2.  The migration will create a new fields called fieldJSON : { a : "", b : ""}.  Here a and b are derived from existing fields a1, a2, b1 and b2.

Comment: Understand to avoid loading large data from and back database. But not very clear about the requirements of migration. Any details or simple example?

Comment: Migration example  :  ExampleDoc (collection).   has fields a1, a2, b1 and b2.  The migration will create a new fields called fieldJSON : { a : "", b : ""}.  Here a and b are derived from existing fields a1, a2, b1 and b2.

Answer (score 1):

OK, now I understand that

- you want to create a new field into the same collection which is sharded;
- the content of this new field is generated by existing fields;
- you don't want to fetch these existing fields from database to application for handling perhaps because of large volume;
- you can't invoke `eval` database command because it's a sharded collection;
- you can't un-shard the current collection.

Then, is it possible to fulfill the intent through `mapReduce`?

1. Query the exact document you want to update;
2. mapping, reducing and then overwriting the original document of this collection by specifying some parameters such as `{out:{merge:<collectionName>, sharded:true}}`.